# Reuse of SSRS Report parameter

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, persistence, reporting

I am new to SSRS, I am creating a report which will take ID's as parameter e.g. 1,2,6,7,8,9 and so on. This parameter will be used for multiple reports. As a good practice I am thinking the user should not enter the ID  for each report. Once entered/selected the ID parameter should be persistent for all the reports.

I am using Visual Studio 2008 to create the report and SQL Server 2008 R2 for backend scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in an elegant way, but requires some work on the back end database.

If your reports are executing stored procedures, you can have the stored procedure for each report write the user's choice of a parameter to a table. Then the next report can check that table for a value. You could design this to be user specific, time-dependent, etc., depending on the effort you put in. It might be cleaner to set the parameter in a separate dataset. That is, in each report, you have multiple datasets. One grabs the parameter value, and your report parameters will default to that result. The other report data set can display the "main data."

Comment: That is a great idea. When the use loads the first report, ID parameter will be filled, I will then store it in temp table. The subsequent reports can use the value from that table. The question is when will the table with ID's be cleared?

Comment: You could store the time of the previous request, and clear out old ones, or just separately schedule them to be cleared out on a regular basis.